# final or nulling views after use? What is more optimal?

Tags: android, performance, optimization

I'd like to make my app as optimal as possible. Which code is more optimal (speed, memory usage etc) and why? What do you think ;-)?

1.

```
    final Button testButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.testButton);
    testButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
                 (some code here)
        }
    });
```

2.

```
    Button testButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.testButton);
    testButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
                 (some code here)
        }
    });
    testButton = null;
```

ps. Do you have any Android code optimization tips?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Optimization of Android Applications](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3545345/optimization-of-android-applications)

Comment: check this http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-tips.html

Comment: Thank you. I've read it and I'm still not sure. Is static final more optimal?

Comment: Why do you have a doubt about it...it's good practice to declare constants static final

Comment: where do you see constants?

Comment: @WarrenFaith Asking whom..?

Comment: both of you. There is no "static final" in the question... correction, there was no static...

Comment: I've corrected the question.

Comment: @WarrenFaith I haven't mentioned. what I have just provided the link to performance optimisation tips by developers.android.com, and He asked about static final. ok..? And then I have replied to his query, I didn't say his code have constants..? see the conversation

Comment: "static final" in his context does not even compile...

Comment: @WarrenFaith oh man , I know that..why are you saying to me..I haven't suggested him to use constants, He asked about static final, I said "it's good practice to declare constants static final" for his question "Is static final more optimal?"

Comment: This wasn't directly targeted at you should have checked that in the context of the question, there was no constants to talk about so asking about "static final" as a option should have raised questions. Anyways with the given 2 answers below, androfan should have his answer...

Comment: Yep. You've got right. Anyway, thanks for valuable links and hints ;).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt this is the bottleneck in your app. I would not worry about this at all.

Also if the `testButton` is a local variable it will go out of scope without when the method returns and setting it to null will have no effect. Using or not using final in one single row of code in your app will not be measurable. Try making the parts where the user actually needs to wait for something faster instead.

That said, I feel having the final keyword in there makes the code more readable.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with vidstige.

You just added `static` to your question and that doesn't make sense there. A static final is meant to be used for constants only.

Also static final variable definition in a method does not compile! So skip it. Final would be enough there and is basically an insurance that you don't reuse the variable if you don't meant to do it.